# save chart image on file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
 public void SaveFileOnDisk(Chart ms, string FileName)
{
    try
    { 
        string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
        string physicalPath =  HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(appPath);
        string strpath = physicalPath + "\\Images";
        string WorkingDirectory = strpath;

        ms.SaveImage("\\\\servername\\Testing" + "\\" + FileName + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("ddmmyyyy") + ".png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

i want to save image on file server folder getting error Access to the path   '\SERVERNAME\Testing\test09002016.png'  is denied.

i have credentials for file server, but how to use them while saving image?

Comment: Can you make sure that you have write permission on your Testing folder?

Comment: No, my user don't have access to that folder to write file.
But can i write image using map drive or something else through code.

Comment: True. But even application has that permission to save anything in that folder.

Comment: So please give write permission to your Testing folder, then you will be able to save images.

Comment: ok checking for that,But can't i save image only using file server details(Domain name,User name, Password) through network drive mapping like that.

Comment: You did correct thing, just error is related to permission, access denied. So once you assign proper permission your issue will be solved.

Comment: When you say _my user_, is this the user that your IIS application's app pool is using?

Comment: @Richard Everett Yes.

Comment: Quick and dirty hack is to use "App_Data" directory, it should have Write permission for your app by default. But it is far from best practices.

Comment: Troubleshooting suggestions: Change the app pool user to your own Windows credentials (assuming you can access that share), and re-test.

Comment: @Richard Everett are asking to set app pool user with server credentials?

Comment: Trying to establish if the user you're using for the app pool actually has the server credentials you think it has.